# es6 How to import only one part from module and don't execute other parts

Tags: import, ecmascript-6, export, browserify

I have folowing module called code-style:

```
import fs from "fs";
import css from "insert-css";

export var master = (function(){
    let styles = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+"/sheets/master.css","utf8");
    css(styles);
    return styles;
})();

export var colors =  (function(){
    let styles = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+"/sheets/colors.css","utf8");
    css(styles);
    return styles;
})();

export var banner =  (function(){
    let styles = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+"/sheets/colors.css","utf8");
    css(styles);
    return styles;
})();

export var busy1 = (function(){
    let styles = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+"/sheets/colors.css","utf8");
    css(styles);
    return styles;
})();
```

And I do:

```
import {master} from "code-style";
```

Now the problem is, that all the functions inside the module are executed when I do my Import, but I want just `master` to be executed.

I have no Idea how to achieve this.

I need to keep my Import how it is and can't add aditional code after the import, the functionality and function call must stay inside the module.

Any ideas?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Ps: the code is on client-side, using browserify and babel.

Comment: The JS file must be executed in totality-you can't arbitrarily stop JS from running. You could either break it apart more, or change how the module is used.

Comment: Ok I see, how would you break it apart ?

Comment: Separate files. IMO Ori's solution is better, though--it's the only way you have explicit control over when the functions are called.

Answer (score 0):

You use IIFEs (Immediately Invoked Function Expression), JavaScript functions that run as soon as they are defined (imported in this case). Change all IIFEs to functions, and call them when you need them.

So for example, this:

```
export var colors =  (function(){
    let styles = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+"/sheets/colors.css","utf8");
    css(styles);
    return styles;
})();
```

Should be change to this:

```
export var colors = function(){
    let styles = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+"/sheets/colors.css","utf8");
    css(styles);
    return styles;
};
```

And after you import it call it, like this:
    import {colors} from "code-style";
    colors();

After the change, you'll call `master`, and invoke the function:

```
import {master} from "code-style";
const masterCSS = master();
```

Comment: Yes, I already did it like this before, and wanted now to omit this extra call

Comment: In this case the extra call is required.